# Iphone and ipad not showing website correct

Tags: iphone, wordpress, ipad, responsive-design

I have tried to make this website responive: http://www.minicampingdevlegel.nl

It works great in Google Chrome, but when I loop on my iPad Air and iPhone 6s it looks very small.

Is there a problem with my viewport settings?

Answer (score 0):

Could try adding the following viewport tag in the  tag...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
```

I hope this helps...

Comment: I have tried al kinds of different viewports. Currently I have: 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />